# C++/WinRT: Does it make any sense to put keywords on runtime class implementations?

Tags: c++, performance, uwp, windows-runtime, idl

I'm trying to maximize my UWP client application performance to compensate for the slow backend, which I am not the author of.

In some Microsoft's video, I've seen that putting `[noexcept]` in IDL classes can make method calls more efficient, but what about their C++ implementations? Do keywords like `inline`, `noexcept`, or `const` change anything since the whole thing is COM-based, and these methods are not called the same way as in raw C++?

```
// MyViewModel.idl
namespace MyApp
{
    [bindable]
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MyViewModel 
    {
        MyViewModel();
        [noexcept] Int32 MyProperty;
    }
}

// MyViewModel.h
namespace winrt::MyApp::implementation
{
    struct MyViewModel : MyViewModelT<MyViewModel>
    {
        MyViewModel() = default;

        inline int32_t MyProperty() const noexcept;
        inline void MyProperty(int32_t) noexcept;

        private:
        int32_t m_myProperty;
    };
}

// MyViewModel.cpp
namespace winrt::MyApp::implementation
{
    inline int32_t MyViewModel::MyProperty() const noexcept
    {
        return m_myProperty;
    }

    inline void MyViewModel::MyProperty(int32_t value) noexcept
    {
        m_myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

This question is focused strictly on the mentioned keywords, please do not post other, unrelated optimization tips.

Comment: More efficient doesn't necessarily means faster (and certainly not in an order of magnitude comparable with a slow backend). [noexcept] is here specific to the midl 3 language. It may/will change the generated (ABI) code, depending on the target language. In the C++/WinRT target case, it will omit try catch block. Not sure what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for commenting. What have you said, is absolutely correct, but my question is about interface implementations (C++) and not their definitions (IDL).

Comment: The way you implement a COM interface is decoupled from the definition. Ultimately, your method implementations will be called, so the faster they are the better, C++ or not. Again, not sure what you're looking for exactly, or what do you mean by " these methods are not called the same way as in raw C++".

Comment: In raw C++, methods are just called(), while in COM job is done indirectly by QueryInterface() and GUIDs. How would you inline a COM function if the caller doesn't have access to the method implementation/body? That's the reason I am asking, I'm just curious if `inline`,`const` and `noexcept` change anything.

Comment: Job is not done indirectly by QueryInterface and GUIDS. These are only used to get references to interfaces implemented by your classes (QI is a moral equivalent to a dynamic cast if you will). But the call is 100% the same. Short answer to your question is "no for COM, maybe if you think it's useful to you".

Comment: `inline` is a linker directive, really. It allows for relaxing the One-Definition-Rule, and is commonly used in header-only implementations. The decision on whether to actually inline a function call is at the discretion of the compiler, irrespective of the `inline` keyword. In case of C++/WinRT when the consumer is in the same module as the implementation, a compiler can potentially inline function calls, even when that wouldn't be possible when following strict COM rules. It's just one giant application of the As-If rule.